# Не могу скрыть изначально картинки в слайдере

Tags: javascript, slider

Хочу сделать слайдер imgs для сайта, у меня есть:
Кнопка назад, кнопка вперед и между ними картинка, которая, соответственно, переключается.
При запуске/перехода на сайт, почему-то, отображаются все картинки до того момента, как я не нажму на кнопку "назад" или "вперед". Далее, все становится нормально: кнопка <-, одна картинка, кнопка ->.

html:

```
<div class="m_slider_list">

         <div class="arrow-1" onclick="previousSlide()">
             <div></div>
         </div>

         <div class="m_sliders">
             <div class="m_list_img ">
                  <img src="1.png " alt=" ">
             </div>
             <div class="m_list_img ">
                  <img src="2.png " alt=" ">
             </div>
             <div class="m_list_img ">
                  <img src="3.png " alt=" ">
             </div>
          </div>

         <div class="arrow-2 " onclick="nextSlide()">
              <div></div>
         </div>

</div>
```

js:

```
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

/* Увеличиваем индекс на 1 — показываем следующий слайд*/
function nextSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
}

/* Уменьшает индекс на 1 — показываем предыдущий слайд*/
function previousSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);
}

/* Устанавливаем текущий слайд */
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

/* Функция перелистывания */
function showSlides(n) {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("m_list_img");

    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }

    /* Проходим по каждому слайду в цикле for */
    for (let slide of slides) {
        slide.style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Подскажите, как можно сделать, опираясь на данный код, чтобы все картинки (кроме одной) скрывались изначально?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  currentSlide(1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело оказалось в другом. Скрипт у меня запускался только после первого нажатия кнопки. Соответственно, я изначально всем другим (кроме первого) блоков прописал свойство display: none. К сожалению, ответ выше не помог т.к. не понятно куда его вставлять.